# Correct model relationship for a "follow" close to twitter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have schema that looks like this:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "email",
  t.string   "username"
end

create_table "followed_users", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "followed_user_id"
  t.integer  "followed_by_user_id"
end
```

Classes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followed_user, :foreign_key => :followed_user_id
  has_many :followed_by_users, :through => :followed_user 

  has_many :followed_user,  :foreign_key => :followed_by_user_id
  has_many :followed_users, :through => :followed_user

class FollowedUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :followed_user, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :followed_user, :class_name => "User"
end
```

This solution is clearly not working for me.  I was wondering if there was a better solution for this relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not have 2 associations with the same name, I think you should rename the fields of your relation table it's a little ambiguous maybe (follower_user_id and followed_user_id ?) :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followed_users, :foreign_key => :followed_user_id
  has_many :followed_by_users, :through => :followed_users

  has_many :reverse_followed_users, :class_name => 'FollowedUser', :foreign_key => :followed_by_user_id
  has_many :users_followed, :through => :reverse_followed_users, :source => :followed_user
end

class FollowedUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :followed_user, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :followed_by_user, :class_name => "User"
end
```

I hope it would help.